# How to get user details in Box.SDK in iOS

Tags: ios, box

I am working with an iOS application in which I am using Box SDK. After authentication process I want to fetch the user details. I am using the below method to retrieve the user details:

```
[[BoxSDK sharedSDK].usersManager userInfoWithID:BoxAPIUserIDMe requestBuilder:nil  success:nil failure:nil];
NSLog(@"BoxAPIUserIDMe : %@",BoxAPIUserIDMe);
```

I get the output:

> 2014-08-07 18:21:10.867 Boxtry[17246:60b] userid: me

I received "me" in the output. Can any one knows how can I retrieve the user details.

Answer (score 0):

Though its too late to answer this but I believe it may be helpful for others.

```
[[BoxSDK sharedSDK].usersManager userInfoWithID:BoxAPIUserIDMe requestBuilder:nil success:^(BoxUser *user) {
    //success block 
    //get user details as below
    self.driveInfo.userName=[user.rawResponseJSON valueForKey:@"name"];
    self.driveInfo.emailID=[user.rawResponseJSON valueForKey:@"login"];
    float q=[[user.rawResponseJSON valueForKey:@"space_amount"] floatValue];
    float totalGB=q/1024/1024/1024;
    float q2=[[user.rawResponseJSON valueForKey:@"space_used"] floatValue];
    float used=q2/1024/1024;
    self.driveInfo.quotaValue=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f MB of %.2f GB used",used,totalGB];
    if (used>1024) {
        q2/=1024;
        self.driveInfo.quotaValue=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f GB of %.2f GB used",used,totalGB];

    }

} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, NSDictionary *JSONDictionary) {
    // [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Space" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sorry, unable to get account info"] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil]show];
}];
}
```